# I'm trying to update the values ​of a table SQL have an error in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update the values ​​of a table, but it throws an error that I have not been able to determine. If you visualize it it would help me, this is what it throws by console:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'name='Proyecto ' status=0 language='PHP' duration=16 advance=16 effec=0.0 where ' at line 1

```
public int actualizar(Proyecto p, int pos) {
        String sql = "UPDATE proyecto SET code=? name=? status=? language=? duration=? advance=? effec=? where code='"+ pos +"' " ;
        try {
            con = conectar.getConexionSQL();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, p.getCod());
            ps.setString(2, p.getNombre());
            ps.setInt(3, p.getStatus());
            ps.setString(4, "PHP");
            ps.setInt(5, p.getDuracion());
            ps.setInt(6, p.getAvance());
            ps.setDouble(7, 0.0);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            return 1;   
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments in the `SET` must be separated by commas:

```
UPDATE proyecto 
SET code = ?, name = ?, status = ?, language = ?, duration = ?, advance = ?, effec=?
WHERE code = ?
```

Possibly unrelated note: do you really mean to update column `code`, which you are using to identify which record(s) should be updated? Although this is valid SQL, this might not really make sense from functional perspective.